# List of items lost when using QueryDict

Tags: python, json, django

I'm sending the following JSON to my webservice:

```
{
"message": "Hello!",
"people": ["Aaron", "Randy", "Chris", "Andrew"]
}
```

And when I access the QueryDict, dict['people'] returns the last item in the list, Andrew, not the list. What am I doing wrong?

When inspecting the object:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`getlist()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist) method:

```
people = request.GET.getlist('people')
```